# Help upgrading Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 driver for Fedora for a more recent one

Tags: fedora, kernel, drivers, dnf

On my fedora 29, I have the following wifi pci device:

```
00:06.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device 1535
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

I'm getting disconnections when I download large files too fast. I'd like to try a more recent driver, but I know nothing about fedora (and I'm using an old fedora on purpose).

How can I replace that driver by a new one?

Comment: So, which driver is actually in use?  You can see with `lspci -s 00:06.0 -k`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs 00:06.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
 Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device 1535
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
 Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

Comment: " ... I know nothing about fedora ..."  Do you feel comfortable trying updated firmware and/or compiling/signing/installing kernel modules?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes. It's a VM so I can clone and test ots of things and if it does not work then I can simply switch back to the other VM (I'm using Qubes). How can I download the new version of this driver or how can I compile a new one?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm wondering if Qubes could somehow be involved here?  Do other VMs perform better (e.g., recent Fedora, other Linux, Windows)?  Have you tried [increasing the Qubes VM DMA buffer size](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/pci-devices/#possible-issues)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs just doubled from 8192 to 16192, let's see. I didn't test other VMs because I dont know how to setup sys-net for them. I think it's not possible on windows also.

Comment: For possible future readers... Is this issue resolved now?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No, it is still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am affected by this bug as well. I use Fedora 33.

This bug also affects Ubuntu. There is already a bug report in Launchpad: [Wifi drops, particularly under load](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1856372)